# overflow-y: scroll causing Chrome F12 Tools Device Mode to Crash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

Yes I know this sounds like a strange one. I have an Angular app with a custom "dropdown" directive.

Part of the CSS for that drop-down is:

```
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 5px 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The custom dropdown toggles open when a parent anchor is clicked and adds a `display:block` to the `div.dropdown-menu` element. If this dropdown is too close to the current display "bottom" in Chrome F12 Tools Device Mode, device `iPhone 6` and overflows below that page view it causes a Chrome v43 "aw, snap" crash:

[image]

If the drop down is at the top of the page it opens correctly like this:

[image]

If I uncheck the `overflow-y: scroll` with Chrome F12 Tools here:

[image]

It will cause a crash as well:
[image]

I have tried using Chrome.exe with error logging on but nothing is logged to the log file.

**What could be the issue here, it looks like it is Chrome F12 Tools Device mode**